# C# linq finding all string values in a list there match in mongodb

Tags: c#, mongodb, linq

My question might not be specific for MongoDb , even though I am using it.

I want to find all records that are contained in my List

Previously I could search with finding OrderNumber `Collection.Find` 
an incoming parameter of a `string orderNumber`

Thus a method collection.find looked like this:

```
IEnumerable<Activity> activity = Collection.Find<Activity>(o => o.OrderNumber == orderNumber).ToList();
```

However, now i want to find List

So do I NEED to modify this statement to be a LOOP to find, or can this be modified to `Find` all the records in the List  ?

```
public static IEnumerable<Activity> GetActivitiesByOrderNumber(List<OrderStuff> orderNumber)
{

     IEnumerable<Activity> activity = Collection.Find<Activity>(o => o.OrderNumber == orderNumber).ToList();
     return activity;
}
```

**Update**

`Error  CS1503  Argument 1: cannot convert from 'JobManager.Models.Activity' to 'JobManager.Controllers.APIs.OrderStuff'`

```
public static IEnumerable<Activity> GetActivitiesByOrderNumber(List<OrderStuff> orderNumber)
{
    IEnumerable<Activity> activity = Collection.Find<Activity>(o => orderNumber.Contains(o)).ToList();
    return activity;
}
```

**Activity class**

```
public class Activity
{

    [BsonId]
    [BsonRepresentation(BsonType.ObjectId)]
    public string Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime? CreatedDate { get; set; }
    public int CreatedById { get; set; }
    public string CreatedByName { get; set; }

    // ..... etc..
 }
```

**OrderStuff class**

```
public class OrderStuff
{
    public string id { get; set; }
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Check out the following working version, I have taken some liberty to change the object names for correct representation of collection.

```
public static IEnumerable<Activity> GetActivitiesByOrderNumber(List<OrderStuff> orderNumbers)
{
   List<string> OrderStuffIds = orderNumbers.Select(o => o.Id);

    IEnumerable<Activity> activities = Collection.Where(a => OrderStuffIds.Contains(a.Id)).ToList();
    return activity;
}
```

**Explanation:**

> Why the original code did not work ?

You are comparing the `OrderStuff` with `Activity`, when there's no apparent relation between the two, mostly you need to compare using the `Id` field

> Modifications required

- Fetch the Id list from the `OrderStuff` List
- Use the same for comparison, when fetching the `Activity` list, by comparing Ids

> Further Issues:

- Even the current solution is a O(N^2) implementation
- Can be further improved by transforming `List<OrderStuff>` to `Hashset<OrderStuff>`, which will do a binary search in `O(LogN)` time instead of `O(N)`
- Something like:

  ```
  HashSet<OrderStuff> orderNumberHashSet = new HashSet<OrderStuff>(orderNumbers);
  ```

Comment: MongoDb doesn't have a direct  Collection.Where    :/

Comment: Seems i have to use  Collection.Find    - of which this mongodb collection is a `IMongoCollection<Activity>`

Comment: `Where` is a Linq API, `Find` is a List method, include the namespace `System.Linq` and it would work. Otherwise you can simply replace `Where` by `Find` and remaining code will remain same. `Where` is better optimized for filtering than `Find`

Comment: Linq 2 Objects that I have used is purely a C# based IEnumerable querying system, which works same for all kinds of database, once the data is fetched in the memory

Comment: I'm just so happy and thankful to you that it is working!   Postman -> web api  through the service service and into the "store" (repository) and pulling back the correct data!     ( I did have to use  a.OrderNumber  but these are details that I had to adjust  )   Awesome thanks again

Comment: Welcome buddy, all the very best

Answer (score 0):

Try this:

```
public static IEnumerable<Activity> GetActivitiesByOrderNumber(List<Activity> activities)
{
     IEnumerable<Activity> activity = Collection.Find<Activity>(o => activities.Contain(o)).ToList();
     return activity;
}
```

Comment: Hey,  so I actually am passing in List<OrderStuff>  and then want to return Activity List ..   I updated the question showing all the relevant code .  hope that it make more sense.  thanks

Comment: Alright, i thought if you have the orderNumbers then you have activities, thoes orderNumbers is from `Activity` right? so, i wrote it like that, think you'll get the point. If you define class `OrderStuff` only for wrap `id`, you can just pass `List<String> ids` then `ids.Contain(o)`.

Comment: It's `o.Id` in the last